# How to reference aggregate root's property/field while initializing child items

Tags: c#

Suppose that I have two domain classes Order and OrderItem where Order serves as an aggregate root containing one or more order items. As follows:

```
    class OrderItem
    {
        public long LineItemId { get; set; }
        public String ProductId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }

    class Order
    {
        public long OrderId { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public String OrderStatus { get; set; }
        public OrderItem[] OrderItems { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, when initializing an Order object together with its line items, is it possible to reference or access the aggregate's root property/field within the child item initializer as demonstrated below:

```
        var order = new Order
        {
            OrderId = 1,
            OrderDate = new DateTime(2012, 6, 1),
            OrderStatus = "OPEN",
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            OrderItems = new[]
                                {
                                    new OrderItem {
                                        LineItemId = 1,
                                        ProductId = "Orange",
                                        CreatedDate = ??? // Initialize this to order's CreatedDate
                                    },
                                    new OrderItem {
                                        LineItemId = 2,
                                        ProductId = "Pear",
                                        CreatedDate = ??? // Initialize this to order's CreatedDate
                                    }
                                }
        };
```

The objective here would be to ensure that the OrderItem has the same timestamp (CreatedDate) - to a T - as the Order. Can that be achieved easily - without (of course) introducing an extra variable to hold CreatedDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference the parent's variable in the initializer but I think the following accomplishes what you're trying to do in similar fashion:

```
var order = new Order
{
    OrderId = 1,
    OrderDate = new DateTime(2012, 6, 1),
    OrderStatus = "OPEN",
    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
};
order.OrderItems = new[]{
    new OrderItem {
        LineItemId = 1,
        ProductId = "Orange",
        CreatedDate = order.CreatedDate
    },
    new OrderItem {
        LineItemId = 2,
        ProductId = "Pear",
        CreatedDate = order.CreatedDate
    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the object you are initializing. For a simple reason too, it would allow you to easily create a cycle.

In your case, you can work around that by moving the create timestamp of the order into a constructor and changing the OrderItems property to

```
public OrderItem[] OrderItems
{
    get
    {
        return this.orderItems;
    }
    set
    {
        this.orderItems = value;
        foreach (var item in this.orderItems)
        {
            item.CreatedDate = this.OrderDate;
        }
    }           
}
```

and possibly making OrderDate read-only. If you have to have a parameterless constructor you can implement the foreach-loop in OrderDate too and back it with a private field - that way everything will be synchronized.

For completeness sake, OrderDate when not using a constructor:

```
public DateTime OrderDate
{
    get
    {
        return this.orderDate;
    }
    set
    {
        this.orderDate = value;
        foreach (var item in this.orderItems)
        {
            item.CreatedDate = this.OrderDate;
        }
    }
}
```

One addition, I'm pretty sure I'd move some/most of the stuff into a constructor - esp the timestamp is a prime candidate for that, same as Id because that way you can make them read-only for the public `public OrderId [ get; private set; }`. Also, I'd suggest using an enum for OrderStatus.

Comment: hmm... that would take me away from the object initializer... About the possibility of creating a cycle - not if the coder knows what he is doing

Comment: **You can't reference the object you are initializing.** Is that for a fact?

Comment: @JohnGathogo why are you so focused on not using a constructor? Also, if you really can't use one and have to have everything in one go - change the implementation of OrderDate to change the CreatedDate of the orderItems too

Comment: @JohnGathogo yes, yes it is - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795460/nested-use-of-c-sharp-object-initializers for others saying the same thing

Comment: Am not focussed on not using a constructor. Believe me, I use constructors - a lot. And am aware of at least several alternatives to achieving what am trying. I just like trying out alternatives ways to accomplish stuff and use what renders well in a particular scenario

Comment: @JohnGathogo There could have been reasons you have to have a parameterless constructor - I was pretty sure you know about and use them ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12367/discussion-between-brunner-and-john-gathogo)